# add a certain page to the end of a multi pages tif files comand line ImageMagick

Tags: loops, append, imagemagick, addition, tiff

im using windows 8.1 and ImageMagick-7.0.8-11-portable-Q16-x86
all i need is a batch file to add a certain image to the end of each multi-page tif file

```
for example:
i have a folder contain:
usa.tif     (1 pages) 
england.tif (2 page)
brazil.tif  (3 pages)
egypt.tif   (4 pages)
france.tif  (5 pages)
xxxxx.tif   (x pages)

i want to add or append flag.png as a page to the end each tif image above

so output will be like this:

usa.tif     ( 2 pages ) 
england.tif ( 3 pages )
brazil.tif  ( 4 pages )
egypt.tif   ( 5 pages )
france.tif  ( 6 pages )
xxxxx.tif   (x+1 pages)
```

P.S
    (this folder will have a new files everyday with new names)
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be as simple as...

```
magick input.tif flag.png output.tif
```

Ideally you would create a powershell script to iterate over all files in a directory.

```ps
 Get-ChildItem "C:\Full\Path\To\Files" -Filter *.tif -Exclude "output_*" |
 Foreach-Object {
      $input = Get-Content $_.FullName
      $output = "output_" + $input
      magick.exe $input flag.png $output
 }
```

I'm never around the windows platform, so I have no idea if the example above has correct syntax, but it should get you started.